# How to return the array with nested array of objects inside completely if I am using spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to map my array and add some extra fields if conditions are met.. It works! my code add the extra fields I needed. But the problem is, My array were not returning completely, the nested array of objects inside returns null [] . I found out that the spread syntax causes the problem? What should I do?

This is my sample array:

```
data = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 6,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 7,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  }
]
```

This is my code that adds the extra field when the conditions are met:

```
[{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": [],
    "d": 3,
    "e": 1,
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 6,
    "c": [],
    "d": 2,
    "e": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 7,
    "c": [],
    "d": 3,
    "e": 7
  }
]
```

```js
data = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 6,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 7,
    "c": [{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }, {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 5
    }]
  }
]
const output = data.map(function(x) {
  if (this.has(x.a)) {
    return {
      ...x,
      "d": "",
      "e": this.size
    };
  }

  this.add(x.a);
  return {
    ...x,
    "d": this.size,
    "e": ""
  };
}, new Set());
console.log(output);
```

I need my letter "c" property not to return null [] but to return the same data before I mapped it.

Comment: I get the whole `c` value with the original values when I run your code with your input.

Comment: `c` in not [] ?!

Answer (score 0):

#### I think this might be a browser compatibility issue.

The spread syntax [is not supported everywhere yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) .

You might want to have a look at alternatives like [Object.asign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
Caution: [it's not supported everywhere either](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility).

#### Or maybe even this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 5}]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 6,
    "c": [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 5}]
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 7,
    "c": [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 5}]
  }
];

data.forEach(function(x) {
  if (this.has(x.a)) {
    x.d = '';
    x.e = this.size;
  } else {
    this.add(x.a)
    x.d = this.size;
    x.e = '';
  }
}, new Set());
console.log(data);
```